# How to pass different numbers of parameters in a same function?

Tags: c#, function, overloading

I got similar questions of this, but not get satisfied answer.

I have a function

```
func(int a,int b)
{
//code....
}
```

This function accepts two parameters (a and b). I want to pass different number of parameters in this same function. I know there is a concept of overloading but I don't know how many numbers of parameters I'll pass. I am working in C#(asp.net).

Comment: Please tell me also that how to do this in C.

Comment: You may want to look at [optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).  It rather depends on whether you are just trying to avoid having several different signatures depending on the features needed for each call, or want to handle any thrown at you like `String.Format()`.

Comment: Are all parameters `int` type?

Comment: @RGI It may be `int` type or it may be different.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [varargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)([params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182366%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in c#) ...

**Example in C# :**

```
public void func(params int[] numbers)
        { 
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
            } 
        }
```

Comment: I have 2 question. How to access the parameters (a and b). And what we'll do when "a" is int type and "b" is string type.

Comment: @Viktor You access the parameters by iterating the arguments array, that's all you can do, there's no 'a' or 'b' :) If you want to pass different types, you'd have to use `params object[]` and do appropriate casts on each element of the array.

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor Can you give any example.